# names that occur the largest number of times in a data set

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

```
users     directory
----------------------
hjsyeh    hellodir ;
awgshd    newdir;
hjsyeh    hidir;
jkdhjk    welcomedir
```

the above given are set of users and the directories they created .How can I get the sum of the users with more number of directories created in unix shell script ?

my output should be

```
hjsyeh -2 directories
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
echo "hjsyeh hellodir ; awgshd newdir; hjsyeh hidir; jkdhjk welcomedir" | \
 sed -e "s/;\s*/\n/g" | awk '{print $1 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

Its output is:

```
  1 awgshd
  2 hjsyeh
  1 jkdhjk
```

*EDIT:*
Output in the requested format with another call of `awk`:

```
echo "hjsyeh hellodir ; awgshd newdir; hjsyeh hidir; jkdhjk welcomedir" |                                                                
  sed -e "s/;\s*/\n/g" | awk '{print $1 }' | sort | uniq -c | 
  awk '{ printf "%s -%s directories\n" , $2 , $1  }'
```

output:

```
awgshd -1 directories
hjsyeh -2 directories
jkdhjk -1 directories
```

Comment: @arun It would be nice if you can ["accept" my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -anle '
    $h{$F[0]}++;
    END {
        $key_max = (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h)[0];
        print "$key_max - $h{$key_max} directories";
    }
' file
hjsyeh - 2 directories
```

This solution will work well if your data is small. With bigger file, you should use some perl builtin `each`, `keys`, `values` to iterate through the hash:

```
$ perl -anle '
    $h{$F[0]}++;
    END {
        while (($k,$v) = each %h) {
          if ($v > $max_val) {
              $max_key = $k;
              $max_val = $v;
          }
      }
      print "$max_key - $max_val directories";
    }
' file
hjsyeh - 2 directories
```